# How to convert html table without <thead> tag?

Tags: html, markdown, flexmark

I am working with flexmark-java for converting HTML to Markdown and am facing a problem with tables.
my HTML tables don't explicitly contain  tags. I want the converter to automatically recognize the first row as the header. Below is a sample of the HTML table structure I'm working with:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Team</td>
    <td>Overview</td>
    <td>Estimated Time</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Arthur</td>
    <td>Needs support for configuring upload recommendation image</td>
    <td>Waiting</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the output markdown:

```
|--------|---------|----------------|
| Team   | Overview| Estimated Time |
| Arthur | Needs support for configuring upload recommendation image |Waiting|
```

because there's no thead declared in the html content,so flexmark put the separator line to the first line.

is there any configuration that can make the Markdown format correct?